# JQuery chain of actions

Tags: jquery

I have a chain of actions that works well:
1- Click on red. Red animate down and grey animate up
2- Click on background (html) grey goes down and red goes up

The problem comes when the user (by accident) clicks the background and then red. In this case it goes 1, 2 and after that:

3- Red goes up

I do not understand why does this step 3 happen and how to avoid it?

Please check your answer [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WG3md/1/)

HTML:

```
<div id="red"></div>   
<div id="grey"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#red {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px; right: 25px;
    width:80px; height:50px;
    cursor:pointer; 
    background:red;
}

#grey{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:-40px;
    width:100%; height:40px;
    background:grey;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function(){   
    $("#red").click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $("#red").animate({bottom:'-80px'},1000);

        setTimeout(function () {
        $("#grey").animate({bottom:'0px'}, 500);
        }, 700);
    });

    $("html").click(function() {
        $("#grey").animate({bottom:'-40px'}, 800);

        setTimeout(function () {
        $("#red").animate({bottom:'20px'}, 1000);
        }, 500);

    }); 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

make use of `.stop()`

```
$(function(){
    $("#red").click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $("#red").stop().animate({bottom:'-80px'},1000);

        setTimeout(function () {
        $("#grey").stop().animate({bottom:'0px'}, 500);
        }, 700);
    });

    $("html").click(function() {
        $("#grey").stop().animate({bottom:'-40px'}, 800);

        setTimeout(function () {
        $("#red").stop().animate({bottom:'20px'}, 1000);
        }, 500);    
    }); 
})
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/WG3md/2/

Comment: In your example, If someone clicks the background and then red, it still makes something estrange